# How to get the next non-blank cell over multiple blocks in 1 formula in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

In Column A, I have sparsely populated data. They are summary statistics about a preceding block. In Column B, at arbitrary rows, I want to retrieve the data in Column A from the next non-blank row. (That would be a summary statistics of the block this row situates in.)

How do I do that in 1 formula?

| Column A [Data] | Column B [Desired effect] |
| --- | --- |
|  | 2.1 |
|  | 2.1 |
| 2.1 | 2.1 |
|  | 3.5 |
| 3.5 | 3.5 |
|  | 5 |
|  | 5 |
|  | 5 |
|  | 5 |
| 5 | 5 |

Comment: Which column is your desired result?

Comment: @Harun24hr: Column B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=byrow(A2:index(A:A,match(2,1/(A:A<>""))),lambda(Σ,+filter(Σ:offset(Σ,9^9,0),Σ:offset(Σ,9^9,0)<>"")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Would you be able to explain how `A2:index(A:A,match(2,1/(A:A<>"")))` works please?

Comment: a. it loosely translates to A2:A11 in the sample dataset b. and how it happens is match can never find 2 when the condition 1/(A:A<>"") is executed across the range; so instead it gives out the last value of the range which has a non-blank value index

Comment: I see. Thank you for explaining. And the `+` part coerce Google Sheet into outputting the first element in the array output of `filter()` right? If I want to use that first element for some further calculation, would putting brackets `()` around `+filter(...)` work?

Comment: Generally not necessary. you could go directly with something like this example `+filter(z,z<>"")*10`

Answer (score 0):

There may other easy way but I can give it at this time.

```
=QUERY(REDUCE("t",REDUCE(1,A2:A11,LAMBDA(a,x,{a;IF(x="",max(a),max(a)+1)})),LAMBDA(p,q,{p;IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>""),q),"")})),"offset 1",0)
```

To make input column dynamic, use-

```
=QUERY(REDUCE("t",REDUCE(1,A2:INDEX(A2:A,MATCH(99^99,A2:A)),
LAMBDA(a,x,{a;IF(x="",max(a),max(a)+1)})),
LAMBDA(p,q,{p;IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>""),q),"")})),"offset 1",0)
```

[image]